# Set up a Timer in specified index of tableView

Tags: swift, timer

I want to set up a Timer in specified index of tableView(index = 2), only countdown 1 second in just one cell, but it affect two cells, so the timer reduce 2 seconds in index 1&2 cells, how can I solve it？
Here is my function：
In viewController:

```
var timeSec1 = 0
var diffSEC1 = 0
var countdownTime = 300
private func setupTimer(sender: TaskTableViewCell, index: Int) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.timeSec1 += Int(timer.timeInterval)
        let nowSEC = self.countdownTime - self.timeSec1
        
        if nowSEC != 0 {
            let sec = nowSEC % 60
            let min = nowSEC / 60 % 60
            sender.goBtn.setTitle(String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec), for: .normal)
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.timeSec1 = 0
            self.queryReward()
        }
    }
}
```

In tableView cellForRowAt（Function is in case 3, rewardAdStatus == 1）：

```
switch task.taskId {
    case 1:
        if isSign == true {
            cell.countLabel.text = "1"
            cell.progress.progress = 1
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_signined, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431373, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8078431373, alpha: 1)
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            cell.countLabel.text = "0"
            cell.progress.progress = 0
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_signin, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = userColor
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
        cell.totalCounLabel.text = "1"
    case 2:
        if bindPhone == true {
            cell.countLabel.text = "1"
            cell.progress.progress = 1
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_finish, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431373, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8078431373, alpha: 1)
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_bind, for: .normal)
            cell.countLabel.text = "0"
            cell.progress.progress = 0
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = userColor
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
        cell.totalCounLabel.text = "1"
    case 3:
        cell.scheduleView.isHidden = true
        if rewardAdStatus == 0, isAdReady {
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_showAd, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = userColor
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else if rewardAdStatus == 1 {
            self.setupTimer(sender: cell, index: indexPath.row)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431373, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8078431373, alpha: 1)
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = false
        } else if rewardAdStatus == 2 {
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_finish, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431373, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8078431373, alpha: 1)
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    case 4:
        if isGetTFMonthGift == 0 {
            cell.countLabel.text = "0"
            cell.progress.progress = 0
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_receive, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = userColor
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else if isGetTFMonthGift == 1 {
            cell.countLabel.text = "1"
            cell.progress.progress = 1
            cell.goBtn.setTitle(.localized_taskVC_received, for: .normal)
            cell.goBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431373, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8078431373, alpha: 1)
            cell.goBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    default: break
    }
```

Comment: cant get ur question and code. 
if u just want a 1 second delay in third cell why dont you use DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(after: .now() + 1) {}

Comment: I have four cell in my tableView, and have button in each cell, I only want my third cell button title to be countdown, but my func setupTimer(), where I use in tableView cellForRowAt (case 3), it cause my second and third cells both be countdown, I don't know why, please help！！Thanks！

Comment: create 2 custom cells with first for 3rd index and second cell for the rest all index
this happens because cell.dequeueResuse all the cells and if u scroll ur tableview it will also change the other cells button title too

Answer (score 0):

First approach is you should create two custom Cells rather than using one
The second is use if else statement in setupTimer function

```
    private func setupTimer(sender: TaskTableViewCell, index: Int) {
     Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.timeSec1 += Int(timer.timeInterval)
        let nowSEC = self.countdownTime - self.timeSec1
        
        if nowSEC != 0 {
            let sec = nowSEC % 60
            let min = nowSEC / 60 % 60
          if index == 2 {
              sender.goBtn.setTitle(String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec), for: .normal)
           } else {
              sender.goBtn.setTitle("Some title", for: .normal)
           }
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.timeSec1 = 0
            self.queryReward()
            sender.goBtn.setTitle("Some title", for: .normal)
        }
      }
      // uncomment this if still its not working 
      // tableView.relaodData()
    }
```

Comment: I use two custom cells, and it works, only my third cell countdown, but there is still one problem, my timer doesn't count right. I get the countdown time from the API, it calls diffSEC

Comment: Use JSON Decode to get queryRewardData, and save the property
self.queryDiffSEC = queryRewardData.diffSEC ;
self.cellDiffSEC = queryRewardData.diffSEC

Comment: I don't know if it is because I use the property more than one time in same time, so it cause timer doesn't count right, please help me！

Comment: yes try to use property of dequeue cells so the behavior will change after you setting up new title to button but not telling the index where to change because you not be able to identify your cell in timer function hence you should set all titles again as i do when index 2 and when not 2